# Why Do I Need A Second Navigation Controller?

Tags: ios

I have the following on my storyboard:

1. A navigation controller with a table view controller as its root view controller.
2. The table view controller's navigation item has right bar button (Add) that segues to a 2nd navigation controller.
3. The 2nd navigation controller has a 2nd table view controller as its root view controller.
4. The 2nd table view controller's navigation item has a left bar button (Cancel) and a right bar button (Save) both of which unwind back to the 1rst table view controller.

This all works fine: I can navigate from the 1st table view controller to the 2nd and back.

If I remove the 2nd navigation controller and instead segue directly from the 1st table view controller to the 2nd then the 2nd table view controller's navigation item is not displayed. What is going on? Why do I need the 2nd navigation controller?

[image]

Comment: can you show ur stroyboard scene, in here if you are present the second VC then need the 2nd navigation controller else no need of 2 navigation controller, if

Comment: how do you present the second VC

Comment: remove the intermediate navigation controller and connect your second VC to initial vc and change your segue type kind model from `present modally` to `show` e.g push

Comment: Anbu Your question (how do you present ...) gave me the clue that I needed. The 1st table view controller is performing a modal segue to the 2nd. When I eliminated the 2nd navigation controller and segued directly to the 2nd table view controller I was still doing a modal segue. When I changed to a Show segue it worked! By using a Show segue I no longer need the 2nd navigation controller.  
I would like to accept your answer but it does not quite say it :-(

Comment: Anbu I just saw your 3rd comment - that is the answer! If you will modify your answer then I will accept it.

Comment: which line if you add in comment i will add in my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> remove the **intermediate navigation controller** and **connect your second VC to initial vc** and change your segue type kind model from `present modally` to `show` e.g push

if you are using present then navigation controller is not a manodatry  but on your save and cancel button purpose you need to embed with navigation controller, in here you **push** then no need of Second Navigation Controller.

[image]

on navigation use

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"sample" sender: self];
```

on your second by default navigation bar will comes, if you need add barbuttons in right and left side, once press the  done  button use the following comment

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

it automatically come back to initial VC,

you can get the detail of segues in [apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/UsingSegues.html)

Comment: if you need change the segue type else you can go as usual

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a second navigation controller. This is what you need to do to after you do a Show segue to the second TableViewController:

1. Confirm that you're actually doing a **Show (e.g., Push)** segue. If you have to do a Present Modally segue, then you will need another UINavigationController.
2. Add a **Navigation Item** (not a Navigation BAR) to the second TableViewController. You'll then be able to add a title, add navigation buttons, etc.

[image]

Comment: Aziz, Thank you for the correct answer; i.e. Use a show segue, not a modal. However, I feel that I must accept Anbu's answer because he started helping me first.